# SEAM2-Application with JBoss 7.1 - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, migration, seam, seam2

i have a "big" SEAM2-Project which should be migrated from JBOss 5.1 to 7.1.

Now i have big problems. One of them is a ClassNotFoundException:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.seam.persistence.HibernateSessionProxy from [Module "deployment.app-ear-2.4.23-SNAPSHOT.ear.jboss-seam-2.1.2.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 53 more
```

The problem is, that the HibernateSessionProxy exists in the Jboss-seam-2.1.2.jar which is in the root-path of the ear-File. So why could this class not be found?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Did you ever get to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

JBoss 7 uses a different version of Hibernate and unless you specifically exclude it that's what will be used. See [this](https://community.jboss.org/blogs/marek-novotny/2011/07/15/seam-2-jpa-example-on-jboss-as7) and [this](https://community.jboss.org/blogs/marek-novotny/2011/07/29/seam-2-booking-example-on-jboss-as-7)
for more info.